# <p> Tags being Inserted in html from plugin PHP not passing through the_content

Tags: php, functions

I have an issue where some raw html is getting

tags inserted where 'the_content' is not at play.

I tried:

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

Already to no avail.

Here is a massivly reduced version of the code that is causing the problem:

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', array('i13woo_extra_checkout_fields'));

function i13woo_extra_checkout_fields() {
?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var myCaptcha = null;
                    var capchaChecked = false;
                    var recap_val = null;

                    function intval_checkout_ready(f) {
                           /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('intval_checkout_ready(' + f + ')', 9) : f()
                     }
</script>
<?php
}
```

And the result when I view source of the page is:

```
<p>             <script type="text/javascript">
                    var myCaptcha = null;
                    var capchaChecked = false;
                    var recap_val = null;</p>
<p>                 function intval_checkout_ready(f) {
                           /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('intval_checkout_ready(' + f + ')', 9) : f()
                     }</p>
<p>             </script></p>
```

Comment: When viewing source, is that the source code from the server, or from the browser (DevTools)?

Comment: From the server.  The <p> tags don't show up in DevTools.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think anyone can solve the source of the issue without poking around the codebase, I think the (untested) code below may solve the impact.

Use output buffering to store the `<script>`, and then remove all the new lines and extra whitespace (tabs, line breaks, multiple spaces).

```php
function i13woo_extra_checkout_fields() {
    ob_start();
    ?>

    <script>
        ...
    </script>

    <?php
    $script = ob_get_return();
    $script = str_replace( array( PHP_EOL, “\t”, '  ' ), '', $script );

    echo $script;
}
```